# Hacer que MainActivity sea una interfaz de búsqueda: no se reconoce el método 'doMySearch'

Tags: java, android, searchview

Estoy tratando de que la actividad principal sea una interfaz de búsqueda. Siguiendo la documentación de Google [Create a Search Interface](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/search/search-dialog), he modificado el AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Minerals.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

No sé si coloco mal las etiquetas para que MainActivity tenga el diálogo de búsqueda, pero al lanzar la aplicación no aparece.

He seguido con el siguiente paso del tutorial, y he añadido en el constructor de MainActivity:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }
```

Lo que me da error de que no reconoce el método doMySearch(query)

```
Cannot resolve method 'doMySearch' in 'MainActivity'
```

Comment: Probaste a implementar un método que se llame `private void doMySearch(String query){...}`? Tienes exactamente el mismo problema que en la anterior pregunta, el tutorial es genérico, no te van a decir exactamente cómo hacer la búsqueda en si misma porque eso cambiará según tus necesidades. Lo que necesitas es implementar tú el método que hace la búsqueda, ellos te han dado todo lo demás... y literalmente, es el mismo error que te daba antes, pero con diferente nombre de método. Ese error significa QUE TE FALTA PONER UN MÉTODO EN TU CLASE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

> Cannot resolve method 'doMySearch' in 'MainActivity'

indica:

> No se puede resolver el método 'doMySearch' en 'MainActivity'

No se puede resolver, ya que el método no existe en MainActivity, probablemente no exista en tu aplicación o existe en otra clase.

Asegura agregarlo:

```
public void doMySearch(String query) {

     //Implementacion.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

¡ Probaste agregar **doMySearch** a tu clase **MainActivity**!
Este método debe ser el encargado de realizar la búsqueda con la consulta que recibe como parámetro

```
public void doMySearch(String query) {
    // aqui realizas la busqueda puede ser local o una APi externa
    List<Result> results = search(query);

    // Muestra los resultados obtenidos
    showResults(results);
```

Y finalmente usando los métodos **search** o **showResults** compruebas si compila

Comment: Sí eso es. Se debe crear el código que genera la búsqueda.

Comment: Esto parece un comentario. Te sugiero leer [answer]. Intenta explicar un poco más tu respuesta, ya que puede ayudar a otros usuarios con un problema parecido y tu comentario tal vez no sea suficiente para guiarlos en la solución, (tal vez no saben cómo agregar el método a la Clase adecuada). Además, una breve explicación del porqué *agregar `doMySearch` a la clase `MainActivity`* es la solución al problema, haría que tu respuesta suba su calidad y visibilidad. Saludos